# How to validate html for a form created with form builder as json form in cakephp?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp, formbuilder

I have used form builder plugin to dynamically create forms and assign them to users to fill data.The form is saved in db in json format with the html attributes and values etc.I want to add validations to that form so that when the user submits the form,required fields should not get submitted empty and it should give error.

Form builder form that is saved in json format in db.
Same json html code is fetched from db and displayed to the user as a form to fill.Once the user fills the form and submits ,js call is made to save the form in same json data with a value.

```
[{"type":"header","subtype":"h1","label":"test","dependent":"0"},{"type":"text","required":true,"label":"name","className":"form-control","name":"text-1569560366315","subtype":"text","dependent":"0","userData":["Amelia Gutierrez"]},{"type":"text","required":true,"label":"email","className":"form-control","name":"text-1569560374018","subtype":"text","dependent":"0","userData":["cuziqutisy@mailinator.net"]},{"type":"textarea","required":true,"label":"Userid","className":"form-control","name":"textarea-1569560381474","subtype":"textarea","dependent":"0","userData":["Eius et hic dolore i"]},{"type":"textarea","label":"contact","className":"form-control","name":"textarea-1569560381898","subtype":"textarea","dependent":"0","userData":["Sit excepteur dolore"]},{"type":"button","label":"Submit","subtype":"button","className":"btn-default btn","name":"button-1569560399786","style":"default"}]
```

**form display code**

```
<div class="formFields form large-9 medium-8 columns content">

    <?= $this->Form->create(null,['id' => 'form-submissions', "enctype" => "multipart/form-data", 'action' => '']) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __($formField[0]['title']) ?></legend>            

          <?= $this->Form->hidden('form_id',['custom'=>'tableData', 'value' => $formField[0]['id'] ]); ?>  
    </fieldset>     
        <div id="build-wrap"></div>
        <div class="render-wrap"></div>
        <?= $this->Form->hidden('field_data',['id'=>'tableData', 'value' => $formField[0]['form_field']['field_data'] ]); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->hidden('form_submission_data',['id'=>'submitted_data', 'value' => '' ]); ?>

        <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Form submission through js

```
if ($("#form-submissions").length > 0){  

        var fbTemplate = document.getElementById('build-wrap');
        var dataTable = document.getElementById("tableData");
        var formData = dataTable.value;    
        var formRenderInstance = $('#build-wrap').formRender({
            dataType: 'json',
            formData: formData
        });


    $( "#form-submissions button:last" ).click(function() {
        $("#submitted_data").val(JSON.stringify(formRenderInstance.userData));
        var $form = document.getElementById("form-submissions");
            $form = new FormData($form); 
        $.ajax({
                url: "/portal/form-submission-datas/add",
                data: $form,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.includes("success")) {
                        let htmlData =
                            '<section class="content-header"> <div class = "alert alert-success alert-dismissible"> <button aria-hidden = "true" data-dismiss = "alert" class = "close" type = "button"> Ã— </button> <h4> <i class= "icon fa fa-check"> </i> Alert! </h4>The form has been saved. </div> </section> ';
                        $("#results").html(htmlData);
                    } else {
                        let htmlData =
                            '<section class="content-header"> <div class = "alert alert-error alert-dismissible"> <button aria-hidden = "true" data-dismiss = "alert" class = "close" type = "button"> Ã— </button> <h4> <i class= "icon fa fa-check"> </i> Alert! </h4>The form could no be saved. </div> </section> ';
                        $("#results").html(htmlData);
                    }
                }
            });

    }); 
    $("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
     });   

}
```

Should be able to apply html validations to this dynamic form.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share the code where you are displaying and submitting the form.

Comment: Added @ascsoftw

Comment: You should validate the form in your JS Function before AJAX Call

Comment: @ascsoftw, remember that JS validation is insufficient, as it can easily be entirely circumvented.